# When did the notion of and term "weight" arise in geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

The notion of [weight of a Hodge structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_structure) and its avatars on $\ell$-adic and $p$-adic cohomologies (via comparison theorems modeled on the Hodge decomposition of de Rham or singular cohomology with complex coefficients) is a little mysterious. Eigenvalues of Frobenius acting on $\ell$-adic cohomology of a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb F_q$ have absolute values $q^\frac{n}{2}$, for some $n$; numbers with this property are called "pure of weight $n$". And an eigenspace of Frobenius for such an eigenvalue are called the same, as is a Galois representation on such an eigenspace.

I wonder whether the term "weight" ("poids" in french) was introduced by Weil, Serre, Grothendieck, or Deligne, or perhaps someone else -which seems less likely. And was it introduced after the formulation of the Weil conjectures, inspired by those, or prior to that consideration of cohomology of varieties over finite fields by Weil ? I could even ask if it was formulated before the idea of a motive, but the answer looks obvious: most probably "yes", as the notion of degree/weight seems appropriate on the basis of the Weil conjectures alone.

Uwe Jannsen cites Deligne's ICM 1974 article on weights in [this overview](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.0927.pdf). I should probably read everything thoroughly, and thus make myself a fairly good picture, but i thought that it might be good anyway to (gather in one place and) read your opinions on the historiography of the theory of weights, and perhaps nuggets of insight on this term and its various guises, which i might miss even poring through the pioneers' writings. Thank you.

Comment: Note it says in the WP article (for weight $n$), "this action must have the property that a real number $a$ acts by $a^n$". Hence I would bet this terminology originates from 19th century invariant theory (homogeneous polynomials), either directly or through the terminology of weights in representations of Lie groups and Lie algebras which, according to https://mathoverflow.net/q/154933/27465, comes from that same origin (via Kowalewski and E. Cartan).

Comment: Dear @TorstenSchoeneberg, Thank you ! :)  This is exactly what i was hoping for, without knowing the answer of course. I am so ignorant of representation theory -while Weil, Serre, Deligne, were experts. Yes of course, weight in geometry is definitely just a particular case of weight in abstract representation theory. Now i could ask whether Hodge himself thought about using the term, but i think it was Deligne who had the idea of characterizing pure Hodge structures as representations of the "Deligne torus" of fixed weight. I needed a representation theory sorcerer to educate me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn my comment into an answer:

As it says in your linked Wikipedia article, a pure Hodge structure of weight $n$ has a natural group action on it, and

> this action must have the property that a real number $a$ acts by $a^n$.

In the representation theory camp, they would call that an action of weight $n$.

In turn, the terminology "weights" (or rather, "poids") in representations (of e.g. Lie groups and Lie algebras), according to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/154933/27465), was introduced in the early 20th century by E. Cartan, in turn influenced (via G. Kowalewski) by [19th century invariant theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_theory#The_nineteenth-century_origins). (Consider a homogoneous polynomial $f$ of degree $n$, then $f(ax) = a^n f(x)$.)